# GN: Replace certain string character with certain mesh in Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Does somebody figure out how to replace a certain string character with a certain mesh in geo nodes?
I've tried but the slice string node doesn't allow field input.
This screenshot is not geonodes, just so you can understand me.
[image]

This other one is what I have in geonodes.
[image]

[image]

Thank you very much.
Miguel

Comment: Please be so kind and tell us more. Did you create the characters in *Geometry Nodes*, or are they available as mesh? How are your *Geometry Nodes* built? Is there a screenshot of it? Possibly it would also be good if you could share your blend file with us: https://blend-exchange.com Thank you!

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for your response. It's a random string inside GN that I want to replace with a different mesh for each character. I mean all A's a cube, all B's an sphere ... like that. I update the post with a gn screenshot (older one was "handmade") and the blend file. Thank you!

Comment: Interesting question, because there is no `String to Value` node. Hm. The solution will probably be a bit clumsy in this case. ...think about it.

Comment: @quellenform It'S actually a pity that there's nothing like that. Not exactly _String to Value_, maybe, but something like _Character to Code_ for example, so that like in Excel you can have a character and get its ASCII code from it. This way you could put the objects in a collection and assign each index to an ASCII code, like "Code-65 = Index of Collection Object".

Comment: Yes, both of them would help. I'm trying with string length but I can't find the solution.
The other problem that I see is that slice string node doesn't allow field input so.... how could we do this for a random number of characters?

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer but sadly not an elegant one. I use a Math node to check a character then use a switch to set an appropriate output value (In my case a position in a texture colour ramp).

Unfortunately, this means that every character has to have three nodes for it - Math, Value, and Switch.

Of course, I will eventually use a slice string to get one character at a time from a longer string and set vaious objects' colours accordingly but it would have been so much easier if there was a character to ASCII or similar.

[image: My (poor) solution]